# checking if a folder exists in certain directory

Tags: shell-script, find, directory

Hi I am currently working on a shell script project and I need to check if a folder, say "cat", exists in a certain directory. Right now I am using the `find . -type d` command, but what if the certain directory is not my current working directory? How can I temporarily change my current directory or is there another way to deal with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a Bourne-like shell, you can use an explicit test:

```
directory="/path/to/some/dir"

if [ -d "${directory}/cat" ]; then

# ...

fi
```

The `-d` test evaluates to true if the file exists and is a directory.

Comment: Does this command also look through all the subdirs?

Comment: No, when you said "exists in a certain directory" I took that to mean a single directory.  See the comment from @Christopher; you can use `find /look/in/this/directory -type d -name cat`.